# If $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ is open, is the intersection of all $f^{-1}(B,y)$, $y\in[a,b]$, open?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've been reading a paper in which the authors seem to (implicitly) state the following:

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$, $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ are both open and bounded. If $b>a$, then

$$\{x\in A: f(x,y) \in B,\quad\forall y\in[a,b]\}$$

is open. Is this true? Could someone provide a proof or a counterexample (or a reference containing either or a hint on how to get either). Thanks.

---

My (poor) attempt at a proof:

$$\{x\in A: f(x,y) \in B,\quad\forall y\in[a,b]\}=A\cap\left(\bigcap_{y\in[a,b]}\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x,y)\in B\}\right).\quad(*)$$

Continuity of $f$ implies that, for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(\cdot,y):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Thus, for any $y\in[a,b]$,

$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x,y)\in B\}$$

is open. Here is where I get stuck; I've been trying to convert the uncountably many intersections on the right of $(*)$ into finitely many ones (finitely many intersections of open sets yield an open set) using continuity of $f$ and compactness of $[a,b]$, but I haven't gotten very far.

I've been neglecting the boundedness of $A$ and $B$ in the premise because I can't really see how it would play a role in the proof and I suspect it's only in the paper in order to establish other results. I've also had a quick look through Principles of Analysis by Rudin but I haven't found the result in there either.

Comment: Do I understand that right, you want to prove that $\{x \in A : \{x\}\times [a,b] \subset f^{-1}(B) \}$ is open (or find that it isn't necessarily)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U=\{x\in\Bbb R:f(x,y)\in B\text{ for all }y\in[a,b]\}$, and fix $x\in U$. For each $y\in[a,b]$ there are open sets $V_y$ and $W_y$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in V_y\times W_y\subseteq f^{-1}[B]$. Since $\{x\}\times[a,b]$ is compact, there is a finite $F_x\subseteq[a,b]$ such that $$\{x\}\times[a,b]\subseteq\bigcup_{y\in F_x}(V_y\times W_y)\;.$$ Let

$$V=\bigcap_{y\in F_x}V_y\qquad\text{and}\qquad W=\bigcup_{y\in F_x}W_y\;;$$

then $\{x\}\times[a,b]\subseteq V\times W\subseteq f^{-1}[B]$, and $x\in V\subseteq U$.

Comment: @jkn: No; it has to be the intersection in order to ensure that $V\times W\subseteq f^{-1}[B]$.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: @jkn: You’re welcome.